# Cant get every icons in System settings in Ubuntu14.04

Tags: system-settings

I don't know what's wrong, I can't see any icons in system settings, i'am using Ubuntu 14.04, how can i get it back. There are only 5 icons in settings now.

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and re-installing ubuntu-desktop fixed the issue. You can do that using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

If you get an error about broken packages use the following commands to fix the issue:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Do not accept the first suggested fix but go through the suggested fixes untill you see one that allows installation of the ubuntu desktop.

Comment: @Lonston I fixed the -1 with an upvote; they could've at least told you what the -1 was for so you could possibly improve the post. ohwell